# Were these three the last surviving natural born mutants?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, logan

In *Logan* we have the following interactions:

1. While Logan is listening to the radio and a
   talk-show host says, "It's 2029, why are still talking about
   mutants?"
2. While Charles and Logan are discussing the past and one of them
   mentions "they are all gone" or something like that.
3. We later learn that "they" (they meaning some for of government or
   shadow organization) figured out a way to control mutant births by
   modifying the world's food source.

Trying to connect the dots does this mean that

> Logan, Charles, and Caliban

were the last surviving mutants born naturally? And now,

> that those three are dead. Only the genetically modified children remain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**That's what we are meant to believe, Yes**

However, I don't recall any hard proof from the film that *all* mutants had been wiped out. The Doctor towards the end

> claims to have done this, in addition to the Westchester incident (a la Xavier)

but we do not know for certain. It's entirely possible that there are mutants left that haven't been killed or died of natural causes yet.

In addition, we know that Transigen has access to multiple mutants' DNA, so there's the possibility of one or two being held prisoner by Doctor Rice.

EDIT: Thanks to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/154291/78856) insightful answer from @KutuluMike in the question "What happened to Magneto?" It can also be assumed that some mutants could have fled to other countries, based on the fact that

> The Reavers won't follow the children into Canada