# What happened to Magneto?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, magneto, logan

Magneto was MIA in the movie Logan. Chronologically, he was last seen near the end of *Days of Future Past*, in 2023. It would seem he hasn't seen Charles, Logan, and the X-men since then.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here to suppose the downvotes are for one or both of the following reasons.   (1) It's not about Magneto, why ask about him and not others  and (2) Do you not realize the 2023 in DOFP is a completely different timeline?   That is sort of a key plotpoint of DOFP.

Comment: I suspect some of the downvotes are because this is indictive of the kind of 'template question' that we get after all such movies, where people run down the entire list of irrelevant characters that weren't mentioned and ask where they were. Those questions are in some sense "not useful" and downvoting is one way some people might express dislike for them and discourage any more of them.

Comment: Magneto leaves at the end of each film, so I assumed he wasn't in Westchester.

Answer (score 17):

We have no idea where Magneto or any of the other mutants are. *As far as we know*, they're probably dead.

---

For starters, *Logan* was a movie about Logan, not Wolverine, and not the X-Men. The rest of the world's mutants were purposefully left out of the movie because they were irrelevant to the point: Logan's final journey of discovery.

However, there are clues scattered in the movie that *might* explain where everyone else is. First of all, there's multiple references to the "Westchester Incident" (not all by name), where Xavier

> killed 7 mutants and injured many other people.

Westchester is the location of Xavier's mansion, where the X-Men HQ is, so we can extrapolate from that the likelihood that Xavier

> killed several of his own X-Men and probably fled into hiding.

There is also a short clip from a radio talk show near the start of the movie, in Logan's limo, where the callers says something like "it's 2029, why are we still talking about mutants?". This implies that, to the average person, mutants are a thing of the past.

Finally, one of the Reavers remarks to Caliban that he "used to track muties" for them. From this we can probably guess that the Reavers used to hunt down "dangerous" mutants for Alkali, and the fact that he stopped could mean there just aren't any left worth hunting down.

However, there is one small twist near the end of the movie:

> Alkali won't send the Reavers into Canada after the children, who believe there's a safe haven there.

So it's *possible* that the remaining mutants have merely fled to safety and are in hiding elsewhere, we just don't know.

Comment: I would also add, it appears given the backstory in the XCU that Eric Lehnsherr is older than Charles Xavier, and Xavier is already a nonagenarian in *Logan*, so it really doesn't require any explanation why Magneto is dead (assuming he is).   It is the most likely option independent of anything else that might have happened in the past.

Comment: What do you mean it's not about Wolverine? Logan is Wolverine.

Comment: Wolverine is the name of a hero that works with the X-Men to help people and fight bad guys. That guy is gone. Logan clearly wants nothing to do with that identity or his history. He's just Logan -- just a guy trying to make a living.