# Is Sabretooth still alive?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

I don't understand why this character is still alive, I thought he had died in another movie. I thought Logan had killed him. Did they resurrect him? Or was he rescued by someone?

I don't know if I'm lost between movies but there must be something I did not understand, because this character comes out again?

PS: I was confused about x-24 and Sabretooth, sorry.

Comment: Sabertooth wasn't in Logan

Comment: So, who is the last enemy in the logan film?

Comment: @Gawey You probably mean X-24, a feral clone of Wolverine/Logan. http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-24_(Earth-TRN414)

Comment: Take a look at [this page](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Sabretooth). It might answer some of your questions.

Comment: @tobiasvl ohh yes thank you, I was confused about X-24 i thinks he was victor creed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I don't understand why this character is still alive, I thought he had died in another movie. I thought Logan had killed him. Did they resurrect him? Or is he rescued by someone?

In what movie did Logan kill him? That never happens.

Sabretooth first appears in *X-Men*. In this movie he's a part of Magneto's Brotherhood of Mutants. Near the end of the movie he fights Wolverine at the Statue of Liberty. It's Cyclops who appears to kill him by blasting him off the statue.

He didn't die, however – a scene near the end of *X-Men* hints at his survival, in *X2* his name appears on a list of mutants on Stryker's computer, and he was originally slated to appear in *Logan* – but we never see him again chronologically in the movies, so I'm not sure where you think you see him again. How he survives is left ambiguous, but he has regenerative abilities, so it's not too surprising.

(Note that Sabretooth *does* appear in *X-Men: The Official Game*, a game that covers the events of *X2* and *X-Men: The Last Stand* and apparently is canon with the movies. This game shows that Sabretooth clearly survived the events of *X-Men* (as I noted above), and does ends with Wolverine seemingly killing Sabretooth. Is this the event you're referring to? Sabretooth doesn't appear after this in the continuity, though, so he might actually have died there. On the other hand, there's not a lot of canon to go on after these events, and as I mentioned he was planned for inclusion in *Logan*, so perhaps he survived.)

In the prequel *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, we see an earlier version of Sabretooth. Near the end of this movie, Sabretooth and Wolverine part ways.

> I don't know if I'm lost between the movies but there is something I do not understand, because this character comes out again?

Between what movies? When does he come out again? He never appears again chronologically in the movies after *X-Men*, although he survived.

Since you tagged your question with [logan](/questions/tagged/logan), I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that you thought the character X-24 in *Logan* was Sabretooth. He's not; X-24 is a younger and more feral clone of Wolverine/Logan.

Comment: yes, @tobiasvl thank's you i think's this "I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that you thought the character X-24 in Logan was Sabretooth. He's not; X-24 is a younger and more feral clone of Wolverine/Logan."

Answer (score 5):

Sabretooth was not in the film. His character was going to be included but the writers decided against it.

> “There was a moment when we were thinking about, as I recall, Jim [Mangold] had an idea where when they were on the run, and they go to the gambling town, there may have been at that point they were going to see [Sabretooth] for help,” Frank said. "He was going to be there for help. Now that you mention it! I wouldn't swear to it, but we thought that would have been an interesting thing to do. And then for whatever reason we didn't do it.”
>   <sub>[Cinablend interview: Scott Frank](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/03/03/logan-originally-planned-to-feature-sabretooth/)</sub>

It would seem his character was part of the giant list of dead mutants that are covered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154060/were-these-three-the-last-surviving-natural-born-mutants) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154289/what-happened-to-magneto/154291#154291)